# setTimeout inside for loop in React component never stops iterating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, settimeout

I am trying to create a simple counter component in React. It should start at 0, then iterate up to the passed in number. Here is the code I currently have:

```
const Counter = ({ number }) => {
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState(0);

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + 1), 2000);
  }

  return <span>{currentNumber}</span>;
};

export default Counter;
```

What happens when I run this, is it basically keeps counting forever. `currentNumber` never stops incremementing, even once the `number` has been reached.

Comment: `useEffect` will be called every time your component renders.  Your component will rerender every time you change the state using `setCurrentNumber()`.  Every time `useEffect()` is called it will call `setCurrentNumber()` from 0 to number - 1.   Say number is 50, the first time your com ponent renders it will call setTimeout() 50 times, all calling setCurrentNumber(1).   There is nothing that seems to be comparing currentNumber to number...

Comment: You are making setTimeouts * number every time component renders. so it loops forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `currentNumber` as a dependency for `useEffect()`. This way `useEffect()` will get triggered every second and a new timeout will be registered but only as long as `currentNumber` is smaller than `number`.

```js
const Counter = ({ number }) => {
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(currentNumber < number) setTimeout(() => setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + 1), 1000);
  }, [currentNumber]);

  return <span>{currentNumber}</span>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Counter number={20}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This worked! Question - how could it up to have a trigger for the counter to begin? Say, if wanted to have a function called startCounter, how could I set that up outside of the useEffec?

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [this](https://w3collective.com/react-stopwatch/). A stopwatch is a pretty common project to get started with React.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    if (currentNumber >= number) return;
    setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + 1);
    }, 1000);
}, [currentNumber]);

return <span>{currentNumber}</span>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and it's getting stuck. Reason:

You're scheduling 5 timers which will all update `currentNumber` to `currentNumber + 1`. `currentNumber` is `0`, so it will update `number` times to `1` after 2 seconds. You can approach this with an interval or a `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentNumber < number)
    setTimeout(() => setCurrentNumber(n => n + 1), 2000)
}, [number, currentNumber])
```

If you're using an interval, make sure you return a cleanup callback from `useEffect`, like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = useInterval(...)
  return () => clearInterval(id)
}, [...])
```